How to use a .pem certificate with a web socket client for authentication?
I am trying to use a .pem certificate to connect to a server using websockets as required.
They required using a token and the certificate.
First, I tried to add the certificate in the header along with the token.
I got an error 413.
Then I tried the code below.
I got an unauthorized error.
What could be the solution according to you?
I am using python 3.11 and websocket-client library 1.8.0 .

import websocket
import json
import base64
def get_certificate(pem_file_path):
    with open(pem_file_path, 'rb') as file:
        return file.read().decode("utf-8")


def generate_auth_header(token):
    header_info = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
        "host": HOST,

        #"ClientCertificate":  get_certificate("certificate_path.pem")
    }

    json_header = json.dumps(header_info)

    b64_header = base64.b64encode(json_header.encode()).decode()

    return b64_header

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_open(ws):
    print(ws)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_close(ws, status_code, close_msg):
    print(close_msg)
    




ws_endpoint_with_header = (
        f"{url_wss}?header={generate_auth_header(TOKEN)}&payload=e30="
    )
    
ws = WebSocketApp(
    WsEndpoint,
    on_open=on_open,
    on_message=on_message,
    on_error=on_error,
    on_close=on_close,

)
ws.run_forever(sslopt={"ca_certs": "certitiface_path.pem"})


